# How to build PDFium with emscripten

Tags: emscripten, pdfium, webassembly

I was wondering if someone could walk me through the steps to build PDFium using emscripten to produce a web assembly module.  I can see that PDFium seems to support this type of build based on this ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804907

I can't seem to find documentation on executing this build.